# Google Maps API: Standart (new) balloon style

Tags: css, google-maps, balloon

How to make standart balloons like new restiled google maps ballons?

See pictures:

New styled balloons: [image]

old styled balloons (i have): [image]

Where i can get css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps often put new functionality in their own maps before making them public in their API.

I believe this is a custom info window and there are images involved.

So you can't just put some CSS to style the old balloon into the one you're seeing on Google Maps.

What you have to do is if you want the new styled balloon, you have to create one yourself with the Maps API.

This is called a [Custom Info Window](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=maps%20api%20custom%20info%20window)

This is pretty intensive if you never did some Maps API development.

If the "new style" balloon becomes popular, they will push the update through a new version of the API so it can be available to everyone. They did this with the zoom control, etc.

I'm a certified Maps API developer so I'm pretty sure of my answer!

Thank you

Comment: There are plenty of libraries out there that gives you custom info windows, you can pick one you like also instead of trying to reproduce this one. Just a thought. Thanks!

Comment: Also, to get a preview of custom controls and info window, check out one of my sample: http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html